# Div with sprite image

Tags: html, css, image, sprite

I have three images in a single png made ​​by the sprite method and i want a table inside of the 3rd image.

I want to put the 1st image(maquina_bola) over the 2nd image(maquina_vidro) and the 2nd over the 3rd(maquina_azul) without change the position of the table.

I can do it with separate images files, as in the example code. But using the same code with sprite images, the images are not overlapped.

Someone can help me?

```
<div class="maquina maquina_azul">
                        <div class="maquina_vidro"></div>
                        <div class="maquina_bola"></div>
                        <div style="padding-top:250px; padding-left:20px;">

                        </div>
                    </div>
```

[Fiddle 1 - sprint image](http://jsfiddle.net/PMPTUga/Yy3zZ/)

And must become like this

[Fiddle 2- Perfect](http://jsfiddle.net/PMPTUga/b8AeC/1/)

Comment: please make a fiddle.

Comment: I edit my question. See if you understand now what is my problem. thanks.

Comment: I still want you to make a fiddle, because it makes it easier for me to help.  Can you do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There you go: http://jsfiddle.net/Yy3zZ/1/

1) The order of the images was wrong. The ball has to be behind the bowl.
2) The images have to overlap, so their `position` must be set to `absolute`
3) The container (`_azul`) has to be `relative` positioned
4) You then have to tweak the `left` and `top` properties of each image so they are in the correct position.

```
.maquina_azul{ 
    background: url('http://img823.imageshack.us/img823/7182/wpbl.png') no-repeat -2px -4px;
    width: 290px; height: 710px;
    position:relative;
    margin-top:40px;
}

.maquina_bola{ 
    background: url('http://img823.imageshack.us/img823/7182/wpbl.png') no-repeat -60px -768px;
    width: 176px; height: 176px;
    position:absolute; 
    left:60px; top:-35px;
}

    .maquina_vidro { 
    background: url('http://img823.imageshack.us/img823/7182/wpbl.png') no-repeat -378px -1610px;
    width: 224px; height: 110px;
    position:absolute; 
    left:35px; top: 43px; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way to sprint image is:

[Sprite Cow - Generate CSS for sprite sheets](http://www.spritecow.com/)

And it also works in offline mode ;)